# Roles claim on Web API (bearer token)

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I am using identityServer3 and used cookie based authentication for MVC app and then i use access token and send it in header for bearer based authentication for API. 
I have user roles in claim on MVC app but i need to get those roles on API side. I tired to set up scope claim and map role claim to my API Resource type scope but that doesn't work.

Looking forward for some suggestion/direction.

Keep in mind that the STS, MVC and API clients live on separate servers.

Comment: To add claims to the access token, you need to configure the claims on the Scope definition.

Comment: Thanks Allen. My bad.. i actually figured out same from IdentityServer forum but missed to add data to ScopeClaim Table. Thanks again for your help.